# serialization of enum results in int

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, system.text.json

When i do a GET request to retrieve my list of Persons the enums(Title) get converted into integers:

```cs
class Person {

public Title PersonTitle{ get; set;}
public string Name { get; set;}


}

enum Title {
   STUDENT,
   TEACHER,
   DIRECTOR
}
```

Let's Say we have the following situation:

```cs
Person first = new Person(){
  PersonTitle = Title.STUDENT,
  Name = "Dave"
}
```

this wil result in the following JSON:

```json
[
 {
   "Name" : "Dave",
   "PersonTitle" : 1,
 }
]
```

How do I get the real value of the enum (STUDENT in this case) ?

Comment: `public Type { get; set;}` you missing something here??

Comment: I forgot the name of the property but that's not the problem. It's edited now

Comment: An enum *is* an integer. An enum value is By default enums are serialized as integers. Both JSON.NET and System.Text.Json can be configured to serialize them using their tag names instead. Which one are you using? For System.Text.Json check [Enums as strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0#enums-as-strings)

Comment: When i do a Get request, my method sends a list with those persons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only code that had to be changed was:

**Before** :

```cs
public enum Title {
   STUDENT,
   TEACHER,
   DIRECTOR
}
```

**After** :

```cs
using using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum Title {
   STUDENT,
   TEACHER,
   DIRECTOR
}
```

Now the response looks like:

```json
[
 {
   "Name" : "Dave",
   "PersonTitle" : "Student",
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the [JsonConverterAttribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonconverterattributeproperty.htm)

```
class Person {

[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
public Title PersonTitle{ get; set;}
public string Name { get; set;}


}
```

Updating Enum with [EnumMemberAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=net-5.0)

```
enum Title {
   [EnumMember(Value = "Student")]
   STUDENT,
   [EnumMember(Value = "Teacher")]
   TEACHER,
   [EnumMember(Value = "Director")]
   DIRECTOR
}
```

Comment: I get:  InvalidOperationException: The converter specified on 'MyClass.Person.FileType' does not derive from JsonConverter or have a public parameterless constructor.

Comment: @schweppes0x Are you using newtonsoft or System.Text?

Comment: Newtonsoft and I am not sure why but now I am not getting any error but the JSON is still not correct and still displays integers.

Comment: @schweppes0x: can you try adding [EnumMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.enummemberattribute?view=net-5.0) i.e  `[EnumMember(Value = "Student")]`

Comment: but the value is unknown so maybe the Value is teacher and not student

Comment: @schweppes0x: What you mean by  *"value is unknown"*? What I meant is to decorate the enum with EnumMember. Have you tried doing it?

Comment: I tried it and sadly it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the adequate converter to the JSON serializer.

`System.Text.Json`:

- Use [JsonStringEnumConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter) class.

`Json.NET`:

- Use [StringEnumConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) class.